# How create advanced type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to generate a similar type using TypeScript?

```js
type: {
  name1: SomeType;
  name2: SomeType;
  ....
  nameN: SomeType;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean an interface?

Comment: Type aliasing? `type Reusable = SomeType`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}
```

then you can define your variable as:

```
let type:Dictionary<string> = {
  name1: "val1",
  name2: "val2",
}
```

or

```
let type:Dictionary<number> = {
  name: 15,
  key: 2,
  otherName: 3.4,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
type SomeType = string;

type KeyRange = '1' | '2' | '3';

type KeysNamedInRange = {
  [k in `name${KeyRange}`]: SomeType;
};

const obj: KeysNamedInRange = {
    name1: 'hello',
    name2: 'world',
    name3: 'goodbye',
    name4: 'oops!' // type error
}
```

Comment: Note that this requires support for template literal types, which wasn't introduced until TS 4.1.